# input field must disabled until radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html

I have four fields, two of them is a text input field and the other is a radio button. The thing is I want the text field to be enabled only if select corresponding radio button.

I tried with onclick and oncheck functions inside radio tag but its working for enable the textbox but disable not working

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="customurl" onclick="document.getElementById('text').removeAttribute('disabled')">
  <input type="text" id="text" name="custom1" placeholder="should be 5 charecters at least" disabled>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="customurl" onclick="document.getElementById('sel').removeAttribute('disabled')">
  <input type="text" id="sel" name="custom2" placeholder="should be 5 charecters at least" disabled>
</body>

</html>
```

if I select radio1 textbox1 is enabled and when select radio selected textbox2 enabled but textbox1 not disabled

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work when you switch between the radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

In addition to removing the `disabled` attribute on the target element, you're looking to also *set* the `disabled` attribute on the other element. This can be done with **[`.setAttribute('disabled', true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)**.

You'll also want to remove your `onclick` event handler, and make use of **[unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)** by **[adding an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**. I've used [**`.getElementsByTagName()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) to target the relevant inputs.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('text').removeAttribute('disabled');
  document.getElementById('sel').setAttribute('disabled', true);
});

document.getElementsByTagName('input')[2].addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('sel').removeAttribute('disabled');
  document.getElementById('text').setAttribute('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="type" value="customurl">
<input type="text" id="text" name="custom1" placeholder="should be 5 charecters at least" disabled>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="customurl">
<input type="text" id="sel" name="custom2" placeholder="should be 5 charecters at least" disabled>
```

Comment: thanks for reply and its working fine but i have at least 10 radio buttons with equal text fields.than what to do?